# Parse Facebook Login returns nil

Tags: swift, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using Parse with facebook login, this is the code https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VcXN.png it was working fine and was returning facebook users name,id, email, bio, profile pic, birthday, etc. 
Now it returns only facebook users name and id, thats it. Because of the parse user returns nil and I'm not able to login with facebook now.

```
    var permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_birthday"]


    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, block: {
        (fbuser, error) -> Void in
        if fbuser == nil {
            NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        } else if fbuser!.isNew {
            NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
            self.createFbUser() // Creating the User returns NIL

        } else if fbuser != nil{
            NSLog("User logged in through Facebook!")
        } else {
            if let errorString = error!.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString {
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: errorString as String, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "okay")
                alert.show()
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working now, I used this

```
    FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("me?fields=id,name,birthday,gender,first_name,email", completionHandler: { (connection, fbuser, error) -> Void in
}
```